# Symbol lookup error running 'dot' after upgrade to 22.04 LTS

Tags: upgrade, 22.04

Recently upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and tried running doxygen, which calls dot to generate diagrams.  However, dot would not run.  The error message I get from the terminal when I try to run dot is:

> dot: symbol lookup error:
> /snap/core20/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: undefined
> symbol: __libc_pthread_init, version GLIBC_PRIVATE

Nube to Linux so I'm not sure where to go from here.  I'm guessing that the upgrade generated a conflict with differing versions of 'libpthread.so.0'?  If so, how can I correct this?

Also, to check, I ran 'sudo apt install graphviz' and got the following:

> graphviz is already the newest version (2.42.2-6).
> 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.

Comment: I'd recommend to do a `snap remove graphviz` and then find a ppa or deb for it. (if you insist on using the snap version; you might try to reinstall after the removal). NOTE: This is my general answer for snap packages that do not work "out of the box"

Comment: The application package graphviz is not a snap package.  I think the snap base implementation or one of its installed applications is conflicting with a resource needed by graphviz's dot program.  Just to be sure, I ran "snap remove graphviz" and received 'snap "graphviz" is not installed'.

Comment: Somethoing likel that, but it seems **dot** is the one saying `dot: symbol lookup error: /snap/core20/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: ` - if dot is finding the lib in a snap package then there is serious mixup IMO.

Comment: Or is it the other way; doxygen is a snap package (with an included graphwiz?), and the apt version of dot gets in the way?

Comment: Yes dot is the one saying the libpthread.so.0 file does not contain what it expects.  When I look at the file at /snap/core20/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0, I get "-> libpthread-2.31.so", which, I believe, tends to reinforce the idea that snaps has usurped the libpthread.so.0 file that dot was expecting to find.  I also ran "snap list" and neither dot nor graphwiz were listed.  Is there some configuration item, an environment variable perhaps, that can tell dot to look elsewhere for this library file??

Comment: Is there a snap package that is likely to include libpthread? or might that be core20 itself... Well; https://datacadamia.com/os/linux/ld_library_path - mighht have a way to avoid it; I have not had the need to dabble with it though.

Comment: Accessed the link and tried some suggestions.  No joy.  I submitted a question on the Graphviz forum and received some good feedback from 'smattr', but the result was that exit code 127 relates to not being able to find a file, and there is no reason that `dot` would be looking for some task-related file in `libpthread.so.0`.  I could try installing Graphviz from source but I've never done that before and have limited time.  Maybe someone else will solve this in the near future or maybe I will have more time to devote to this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Found it.  Finally got back to tracking this down and found that Alacritty (terminal emulator) was installed as a Snaps application when upgrading to 22.04 and this is the Snaps application that was causing the conflict.  Removing Alacritty allowed `dot` to run without error.  I switched to a different terminator emulator and things seem to work well now.